# react testing library ternary operator, finding right component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I'm beginner with React testing, learning by coding, here i have a component 'cam.tsx'
i want to test it, when i want to test Add function it goes straight like this, but when i want to test Update function it still shows Add function in my test, how to test both of them ?
Add and Update functions are forms where user can fill.

```js
describe("Testing component ", () => {
 
  
  const Camera = (): RenderResult =>
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Cam
          }}
        />{" "}
      </Provider>
    );

 

  test("Cam", () => {
    Camera();
    const name = screen.queryByTestId(/^AddName/i);
  
  });
});
```

cam.tsx:

```js
     const ADD = "ADD";

   let [state, setState] = useState<State>({mode: ADD });

   if (props.mode) {
   state.mode = props.mode;
   }

 const option = state.mode;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div data-testid="header">
        {option == ADD ? Add() : <></>}
        {option == UPDATE ? Update() : <></>}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
```

Basically cam.tsx is a component which has two forms one for updating camera and another for adding new camera.When user clicks add/update icon then cam component gets 'mode' via props ' state.mode = props.mode '

English is not my mother language, so could be mistakes

Comment: Your code can't run. Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @walee, could you show us more of the cam component code? It would be helpful to see how you are setting state.

Comment: @g0rb added more code, so basically cam.tsx is a component which has two forms one for updating camera and another for adding new camera.When user clicks add/update icon then cam component gets 'mode' via props ' state.mode = props.mode
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to test a component that conditionally renders components from state and can be updated via props.

```
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react';
import {Cam} from './Cam';

test('renders add by default', () => {
    render(<Cam/>);

    expect(screen.getByTestId('addForm'))
        .toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('updateForm'))
        .not.toBeInTheDocument();
});

test('renders edit by passing props', () => {
    const {rerender} = render(<Cam mode={undefined}/>);

    rerender(<Cam mode={'UPDATE'} />)

    expect(screen.getByTestId('updateForm'))
        .toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('addForm'))
        .not.toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

**However**, it is known in the React community that updating state via props is usually an anti-pattern. This is because you now have two sources of truth for state and can be easy to have these two states conflicting. You should instead just use props to manage rendering.

**If state comes from a parent component, use props.**

```
export function Cam(props) {
    const option = props.mode;

    return (
        <div data-testid="header">
            {option === ADD ? Add() : <></>}
            {option === UPDATE ? Update() : <></>}
        </div>
    );
}
```

If you really want to keep state in the child component even if props are passed in, you should update props in an `useEffect` hook. Additionally, you should use the `setState` function rather than setting state manually `state.mode = props.mode`

**Use the `useEffect` hook to update state via props.**

```
...
    const [state, setState] = useState({mode: ADD});

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.mode) {
            setState({mode: props.mode});
        }
    }, [props.mode]) <-- checks this value to prevent infinite loop.

    const option = state.mode;

    return (
...
```

Comment: thanks it works but i got one question related to this same, i want to test if i managed to add new camera but doing this in my test file:   console.log("length:", store.getState().cameras.length) it gives me 0, but doing that same thing in my Cam component it gives me 3, any idea why in test file i'm getting 0 ?

Comment: i made for it own question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73765159/react-shows-wrong-length-testing

Comment: @walee, good. Can you accept this answer as accepted. I'll take a look at your separate question.